# Why do I have to run python again after I updated the .py file?

Tags: python, linux

I am a newbie for Python and Flask. I was a programmer for PHP and CodeIgniter.

Recently, I've enjoyed to write codes for python. However, I found a problem for me.

Here is the hello.py codes.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

After I write down python codes, I have to run it on Linux SSH shell.

```
#python hello.py
```

like this.

Whenever I changed the codes, I must open the SSH shell and re-run hello.py code.

Why do I have to run python again after I updated the .py file?

Is there a way to run the .py file automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask has a [debug mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#debug-mode) for this:

> The run() method is nice to start a local development server, but you
>   would have to restart it manually after each change to your code. That
>   is not very nice and Flask can do better. If you enable debug support
>   the server will reload itself on code changes, and it will also
>   provide you with a helpful debugger if things go wrong.

There are two ways to enable debugging. Either set that flag on the application object:

```
app.debug = True
app.run()
```

Or pass it as a parameter to run:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine. I have one more question. When I hit ctrl + C on SSH Shell. It turns off flask and webpage can't read the server. What should I do if I want to make flask server live?